# Action not working on Permission Denied

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

When my fragment is inflated it opens a `dialog box` for the permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` as required in android 6.0+. I've followed every tutorial but none of my actions execute when permission is given or denied.
I want the app to close and a toast to show when permission is denied, meaning the `permission would be asked again` when the app is reopened.

***fragment start:***

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

View myView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, container, false);
    configureImageButton();
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("App");

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);
        }
    }
```

***onRequestPermissionsResult:***

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Snackbar.make(myView, "Permission Granted.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reopen app and allow permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
    }
}
```

The app does grant/deny the permission but ignores the toast or snackbar.
All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is with the `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`. In your case `onRequestPermissionsResult` will be called in the Activity and not in the Fragment. When you use the fragment's `requestPermissions` function, then it will call the fragment's `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

Comment: @aborocz Your explanation made a lot of sense thanks, I moved the code to my activity instead because it wouldn't work from inside the fragment. Now it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside fragment some changes are there
plz try it like below

```
 private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {


            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

where `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1`  in your case

Comment: I tried inserting the code above but it requires API level 23+ and in my app I'm using (and wish to continue using) API level 19+, is there a workaround for this? Thanks

Comment: if api 19 then no need to check any permition  becase app permition start from 23 api

Answer (score 0):

(1) If your app was already granted, you cannot see the permission dialog by this code.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

So, go to Setting - Application - Your app - and disable your permissions already granted, and run your app again.

(2) Does your onCreateView returns myView correctly? In your sample code, there is no "return myView;"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int RequestPermissionCodeStorage = 105; // Declare Global Variable    

     public boolean checkStoragePermission() {

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RequestPermissionCodeStorage);
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }


    @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {

                case RequestPermissionCodeStorage: {

                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Allow Permission of Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```